# Log in through SSL but display account name on non-SSL pages?

Tags: http, ssl, https

I am building a website with user accounts. I want the user's name to be displayed at the top, along with the ability to check their inbox with a dropdown that will be updated and refreshed by AJAX. For a user to log in, they will enter their username and password in another dropdown box powered by AJAX. I will also have a specific page, which could use SSL, which sells items through PayPal and BitPay.

I want to secure this with SSL. However, it's not feasible to make all the pages use SSL because the CDN I plan to use doesn't support SSL at the price I am willing to pay and because I wish to allow users to embed images and YouTube videos, which would be linking to third-party HTTP resources.

So my question: is it possible to allow users to log in through AJAX securely over SSL? (The AJAX request would be secured, but not the page that shows the log in form.) It must then be able to display their account name and edit their account settings over an unsecure connection? How would cookies work with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get better answers at security.stackexchange.com, but in short: You might have a cookie shared between http and https. But then you should not associate any information to the cookie, which might be abused by an attacker, because the cookie can be sniffed when using http instead of https and then reused by the attacker to hijack the session (and those the identity). So for serious stuff you should have another and different secure (e.g. https-only) cookie.  A good source of information is also OWASP, e.g. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet